# REST API multiple root urls

Tags: rest, api, url

I've got an app with a RESTful API with two main packages.

One package exposes DB models with simple CRUD operations. Its general purpose is just to provide some basic data for another services and front-end app. And it's got versioning to avoid another services errors on updates: `/api/v{number}/`

Other package represents business logic with heavy DB queries to avoid front-end chatty behavior. It's used by front-end app only. There is no versioning.

Both packages use same ORM models and DB.

This app is for internal use, there are no outside customers or users. Just our company.

Main trouble is to decide how to represent these features in URLs. There are two options:

**1. Use same URL root for both packages:**

`domain.com/api/v{number}/...`

**2. Use different URL roots:**

`domain.com/api/v{number}` for simple CRUD api

`domain.com/views/` for business logic api

**First option**.

- Pros:

  1. Our developers can use API without db structure knowledge, just API documentation.
  2. Front-end developers just remember names, not location.
- Cons:

  1. Naming problems. Same entity has different db/business representation. It will cause ugly ambiguous names like
     *entity_infos, entity_details, entity_deep* etc.
  2. Permanent `/v1/` in business API URLs, because there is no versioning.

**Second option**.

- Pros:

  1. There is no URL versioning for business API.
  2. There is no naming problems.
- Cons:

  1. There is no abstraction. You know when is single table used or heavy business logic.
  2. Front-end app uses different API roots with same resource name. It may be confusing, especially for new developers.

As you can see, the pros of one is the cons of another.

I'd like to hear well argued opinion as well as some related links.
Thanks.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but if those resources differ in their representation, why not differ them by representation? `application/vnd.domain.v{number}+json` and `application/vnd.domain.view+json`?

Comment: @sschrass AFAIK it is not very popular solution to distinct resources by MIME types. You should specify headers for any request and hence more code on client-side. It becomes more tricky to build request and looks not very friendly and obvious.
There is one more problem: we use flask-restfult with blueprints on server-side and there is no content-type-based routing out of the box. I believe there is a way to implement it, but it doesn't look like a path of least resistance.

Comment: what you say is absolutely valid. What I believe is also true is, that the same model gets represented differently, so representation is an obvious choice for me. I don't like custom media types in general, but it looks to me acceptable in this scenario. I have no experience with flask, but that there is no routing by accept-headers is suprising me a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a risk reduction point of view, option 2 is preferable over option 1.

As you know, front end developers should never have direct access to business data. If your CRUD API allows this, and your front end developers use it, irreversible data corruption, and  serious reputation and financial damage to the company could occur as a result

Anything that accesses business data needs to go through a rigorous development and testing process. This sort of testing is not performed by front end developers (trust me - I know). Therefore, the business logic developers should be the only ones using the CRUD API. If a front end dev needs data manipulation which is not currently provided by the business logic, then a new method in the API needs to be planned, developed, and tested.

Even if a business logic call simply performs a single CRUD API call, the front end developer does not need to know. All they are interested in is that the data they request or submit will be handled in the correct manner. In the event that database schemas are changed (e.g., during a database upgrade), only a single API needs to be updated rather than have the whole front end searched for API calls. If you have an alias of `latest` referencing the most recent version, and the business logic uses that rather than `v1` etc, the CRUD API can be updated etc without re-writing the business logic API. The REST APIs developed by Atlassian for their applications uses this aliasing. (Have a look [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/) for this. Check out the **'URI Structure'** section)

Separating the two APIs on different URLs clearly shows that they are aimed at different targets. Not letting front end devs know the CRUD API URL brings a level of data security through obscurity. What they don't know about can't bite them.

You always nee to consider the future. You say that the application is only for use "in-house", but what if your company acquires a new business and they start to use the APIs? Do you really want them looking at the data directly? What if public access is allowed to the API? You certainly want Joe Bloggs and his script-kiddie friends poking around in your database directly. Separating the URLs makes this easier to achieve as you can block access to the CRUD API without worrying if there's a backdoor route through to it